# Telerik RadGrid - No property or field 'as' exists in type 'MyEntity'

Tags: asp.net, exception, datagrid, telerik, telerik-grid

The following piece clearly does not have any reference to an 'as' in it:

```
<telerik:GridCalculatedColumn 
    DataFields="MemberFirstName, MemberLastName" DataFormatString="{1} + ', ' + {0}" />
```

Yet it yields this error:

```
Telerik.Web.UI.ParseException: No property or field 'as' exists in type 'MyEntity'
```

As you can see, I'm not looking for an 'as' anywhere and it strictly fails on this specific column only.  `MemberFirstName` and `MemberLastName` will both populate my grid when I separate them from the `GridCalculatedColumn`.  Somehow I am able to use this column type without problems anywhere else.

I know it's looking for 'as', but I can't find out where or why.  Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: If the columns are rendered when separated, have checked the contents on of these column that may cause such an error?

Comment: I've used a test-table containing the data "Tester" and "Name" as the first and last names, both sipmly varchars.  So i'm not sure what else I could do to "check contents on these column that may cause such an error"

Comment: Well, if it is the case then cause must be something to with the `DateFormatString` parser. Have you searched on [Telerik Dev Forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/aspnet-ajax) on the same?

Comment: Have a [Read through this post on Telerik Forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/gridcalculatedcolumn-concatination-with-formatting) and the suggested answer is to use the `<telerik:GridTemplateColumn>` and `<telerik:GridTemplateColumn>' combination to achieve the concatenation.

Comment: Turns out you were right about DataFormatString.  Apparently I needed to have it be `Expression='{1} + ", " + {0}'`.

Comment: Glad that you managed to isolate the issue and address.